# Serverless Cloudwatch events appearing encrypted

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I'm testing out Cloudwatch logs as a trigger for serverless functions. However when my serverless function is triggered, it's just outputting jibberish, which I figured was some form of encryption. Unfortunately I don't know what that encryption is.

Here's the output:

```
{"awslogs":{"data":"H4sIAAAAAAAAAGVR...4BmF05wEAAA=="}}
```

And here's the function's code:

```
const handler = async (event) => {
  console.log('*********RECEIVED EVENT FROM CLOUDWATCH**********')
  console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(
      event,
      null,
      2
    )
  }
};

export { handler };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `"data"` section that you get back is base64 encoded and compressed. To get the information out from the event, you just need to decode the base64 information and unzip the data.

Here's a code snippet that shows basically what needs to be done in order to read the log data.

```
...
    const payload = Buffer.from(event.awslogs.data, 'base64');
    zlib.gunzip(payload, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            ...
        }
        const parsed = JSON.parse(res.toString('utf8'));

        ...
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately I’ve tested base64 decoding it and it didn’t work

Comment: ohhhhhh it's compressed as well ... will test that out